# Moving a list of ints to the front of a list

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting

I have a List of Int64 (List A) that needs to moved infront of another List (Int64) (List B).

List B will ALWAYS contain the numbers from List A.

So say the List A has the following numbers:

```
1, 4, 5
```

List B could then look something like this:

```
1, 9, 5, 2, 10, 15, 4
```

The end result should then look like this:

```
1, 4, 5, 9, 2, 10, 15
```

What is the easiest way of moving the numbers from the first list to the front of the second list?

I thought about removing all List A numbers from List B and then adding them to front again, but I can't seem to grasp my head around the programming itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yo can try the following:

```
var result = listA.Concat(listB.Except(listA)).ToList();
// Gives: 1, 4, 5, 9, 2, 10, 15, 14
```

`Except` removes all elements of `listA` from `listB`. `Concat` then adds them to the front of the list.